# SQL Server : duplicate key from creating unique index

Tags: sql-server-2012, duplicates, string-concatenation, unique-index

I have a table of stock quotes, and dates:

```
StockID QuoteID QuoteDay    QuoteClose
---------------------------------------
5         95    2018-01-03    1.080
5         96    2018-01-04    1.110
5         97    2018-01-05    1.000
5         98    2018-01-06    1.030
5         99    2018-01-07    1.010
5        100    2018-01-08    0.899
5        101    2018-01-09    0.815
```

I create a clustered index to manipulate the data but am running into duplicate key errors with the index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MACD_IDX ON #TBL_MACD_LOOP (StockId, QuoteId)
```

Different combinations of `StockID` and `QuoteID` will result in the same output:

For example `(StockID, QuoteID)` of `(5, 11)` and `(51, 1)` both produce an index of `511`.

My solution is to add "-" between StockId and QuoteId.

Now `(5, 11)` produces `5-11` and `(51, 1)` produces `51-1`.

How do I combine strings with values?

Comment: The full error message you will include the values SQL Server finds as a duplicate key. I expect you will find there is more than one row when you run `SELECT * FROM #TBL_MACD_LOOP WHERE StockID = <value1> AND QuoteID = <value2>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are definitely **mistaken**.

The combinations for `(StockId, QuoteId)` of `(5, 11)` and `(51, 1)` are **two DISTINCTLY different** pairs of values.

They are **NOT combined** into a single value (of `511` as you assume) when creating the index entry. Those are **two different values** and therefore can co-exist in that table - no problem.

To prove this - just run this `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TBL_MACD_LOOP(StockId, QuoteId, QuoteDay, QuoteClose)
VALUES (5, 11, '20180505', 42.76), (51, 1, '20180505', 128.07)
```

Even with your unique index in place, this `INSERT` works without any trouble at all (assuming you don't already have one of these two pairs of values in your table, of course)

Comment: Since I'm getting the duplicate key error, what's the best way to check for duplicates?

Comment: @Coding_Newbie: if inserting one pair of values fails - just run `SELECT * FROM #TBL_MACD_LOOP WHERE StockId = xx AND QuoteId = yy` and find your culprit